# Jetpack Compose ExposedDropdownMenuBox how to change background color?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, material-design

How to change background colour of ExposedDropdownMenuBox ?

[image]

I want to match background colour, transparent would be fine.

Also how to you remove the line under the dropdown?

```
colors = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.textFieldColors(
            focusedTextColor = Color.Red,
            disabledPlaceholderColor = Color.Green
        ) ??
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the `unfocusedIndicatorColor` to remove the **Underline** and `unfocusedContainerColor` to make Background Transparent.

As like above change color when `DropDown` in focus

**Preview**
[image: preview]

**Code**

```
colors = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.textFieldColors(
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                unfocusedContainerColor = Color.Transparent,
                focusedContainerColor = Color.Transparent
            ),
```